# How best to save messages in the chat by timestamp?

Tags: ios, swift, time, chat

I have the following question about creating a chat room. The message model has a `creationTimeStamp` property, it is assigned when the user sends messages from the device. When another user (or users receive this message), at the moment I do not change this property for the time when the message is received locally on the device. Messages I save locally in Realm. The problem is that for example the message was sent at one time to the first users, but because of the slow Internet connection, the second user already had time to send his message (or messages), then the second user appears this message after his sent message to `ChatViewController`, But when he leaves this controller and goes back, his message will be displayed last, and not the message of the first user, since when I take messages from Realm, I sort them by creationTimeStamp. So I want to learn the best practice of saving time stamp, for this case.

Can it be better to change the `creationTimeStamp` when the message is received on the device? But there are also problems here if the user has more than one device. Although I think that this is how messages are stored in iMessage, because they have the synchronization between devices, I attach screensots of the same correspondence, when messages were created quickly.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have best practice for you, only some thoughts.

I think what you want to achieve is quite hard to achieve without inconveniencing users. What I mean is that due to internet connection speed, different users may all have different point of view about timing of your messages. You could correct/sync their view after some time using `creationTimeStamp` to resort messages, but then messages on screen will be reordered which could be annoying.

I guess you could think about different approach - is it that important that all users have the same timeline view? When some time ago we were implementing a group chat we agreed on the notion that single user can have different timeline view. Then we used `recievedTimeStamp` for sorting, for local messages `receivedTimeStamp` is the same as `creationTimeStamp`. It worked out pretty well for us, but of course you can have different requirements.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the experience, I also also thought about what to do to make the separated property about when the user received the message. If after some time there will be no answer, I will answer your questions as correct.